# Celery task state from remote worker 'PENDING' but in fact it's 'SUCCESS'

Tags: python, celery

I have 2 celery workers on different servers.
My first server configuration is:

```py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = env.str("CELERY_URL") # amqp://<user>:<password>@host/db
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = env.str("RESULTS_URL") # redis://<user>:<password>@<host>
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False

CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
# I've also tried CELERY_TASK_STARTED
```

My second server configuration is

```py
broker = "amqp://<user>:<password>@host/db" # same as 1st
result_backend = "redis://<user>:<password>@<host>" # same as 1st
task_track_started = True
# I've also tried task_started
```

Also on my second server I have a task

```py
@app.task(name='Test_task')
def test_task():
    return 'Done!'
```

I'm calling this task from my 1'st server using `task = app.send_task('Test_task', queue='test_queue')`
So
**My trouble is** when I'm trying to get this task status or result it's always same

```py
>>> task.state
'PENDING'
>>> print(task.result)
None
```

But if I check this task in flower its state is *SUCCESS* and its result is *Done!*
[image: Flower Table Screenshot]

I've also tried use `rpc://` as result_backend but result is still same.

My first Celery worker is running on Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64
My second Celery worker is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS aarch64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm too inattentive
I must use `backend` instead of `result_backend` in second configuration